# Laravel composer install giving table doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 5.0 application installed.  To start the base install I cloned cartalyst/platform from github, then added the packages cartalyst/cart and cartalyst/Sentinal.  The initial composer install succeeded, I updated the database information for platform/sentinal and everything worked fine.
The problem came in when I used "php artisan make:model Product" and "php artisan make:model ProductCategory".  The command created files for my new models as well as migration files for the additional database tables.

I ran "php artisan migrate" hoping to create the new tables.  The tables were created, but I believe existing tables were removed.  Now, anytime I do an artisan migrate or composer install/update I get an sql error saying that I'm missing a table called "prefix_extensions":

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'howemerch.hm_extensions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
>   `hm_extensions`)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'howemerch.hm_extensions' doesn't exist
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event
>   returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]   Error Output:

Also, the tables that were created do not use the specified table names in the files for my new models.  The documentation stated that if I specify "protected $table = 'hm_products';" that this would be the table created.

After looking into the extensions table, I see that Extensions is a package that is included in Platform. I've tried running "php artisan platform:install" but that didn't help either.

I'm not sure what I did wrong to drop the old tables or how to restore them.  I tried "php artisan migrate:rollabck" and "php artisan migrate:reset" but both give the same sql error.  I'm pretty new to Laravel, so I'm sorry if there is additional information I need to provide, just let me know.

Comment: Probably you can do ```php artisan migrate:refresh```. This will run every migration again and seed it after that!

Comment: No migrate commands succeed, they all give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've found to resolve this problem was to clean-install Cartalyst.

You can go to `config/platform-foundation.php` and change the `installed_version` to `false`. Thus, you'll be able to do a composer install and go through the installer page again.